# Adaptive payments and preapproved/recurring payments

Tags: paypal, payment

I am in the process of implementing a solution where the user would buy a product using one of two options, either using Credit card or using PayPal. Now basically I would want that the if the user does not have any credits left in his account I charge their PayPal account with a certain amount of money. I am going to use Adaptive Payments for this and I will be using .NET.

Now I have some questions. Does anyone know whether this can be done?
And something else. If I am going to use Adaptive payments.. are adaptive payments more expensive from PayPal side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So just to make sure I follow, their account will have 'credits' to purchase things. They will select items, and check out paying with credits. If the item costs 10 credits and they only have 8, you will charge them the appropriate amount for 2 credits?

This doesnt need to be adaptive payments. All you need to do is edit your checkout flow to account for multiple payment methods (credits and cc or credits and paypal).

So the flow would be like:

Cust adds item to cart -> Cust checks out -> Cart determines if any money is due -> Cart presents new adjusted total (minus credits) to the merchant -> Cust selects payment method and pays.